# Regarding gmail SPF record and A record

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

I have a domain with the following SPF record,

```
"v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:123.45.67.89 ~all"
```

Two questions,

1. Is the IP necessary there? The A record on the domain resolves to the same IP i.e. 123.45.67.89.
2. I've created an email on the domain and added it to gmail to send and receive emails. The emails are working fine, I am able to send emails and they don't have the warning "Google cannot verify if the domain actually sent the email or no". Do I need to add any gmail SPF record to it? I'm asking about this `v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com` record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you have exactly the same IP (or `a:<domain>/<prefix-length>`) in your [`a` mechanism](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#a) (or [`mx` mechanism](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#mx)), the [`ip4` mechanism](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#ip4) is unnecessary and CAN (rather than must) be removed.

   As *domain* is not specified in your `+a` & `+mx`, the *current domain* is used, while `ip4` & `ip6` must always have an `<address>` or `<network>/<prefix-length>` specified.
2. With the current SPF record, Google falls within `~all`, causing `SoftFail`, i.e. "The SPF record has designated the host as NOT being allowed to send but is in transition". Therefore receiving MTA shouldn't `REJECT` the mail, but it can mark it as spam. With `-all` it'd have been rejected.

   Therefore, `include:_spf.google.com` is necessary, if you need to send email from Gmail. However, you should not add another `TXT` record, but combine these two into one, e.g.

   ```
   @ IN TXT "v=spf1 +a +mx include:_spf.google.com ~all"
   ```

   It's also possible (and even suggested on the documentation of [`include:` mechanism](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#include)) to make included domain `Neutral` rather than `Pass`. If Gmail is only used occasionally and you want to prevent other Gmail users to get `Pass` results on the SPF tests, it can be achieved with:

   ```
   @ IN TXT "v=spf1 +a +mx ?include:_spf.google.com ~all"
   ```